# Canceled page load listener because no navigation has been detected

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Unable to click a button . Firefox version 56.0

```
WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) wd;
wd.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-first-form-demo.html");

wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sum1']")).sendKeys("5");
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sum2']")).sendKeys("10");
WebElement e1 = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-  
default']"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",e1 );
Thread.sleep(10000);
e1.click();
```

I want to click 'Get Total' button but "Canceled page load listener because no navigation has been detected" message is showing.

Comment: FWIW: FF 56 is 2+ years old.  You should update FF and geckodriver and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Induce **WebDriverWait** and **elementToBeClickable()** and following **xpath**

```
wd.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-first-form-demo.html"); 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wd, 10); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='sum1']"))).sendKeys("5");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='sum2']"))).sendKeys("10");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default'][text()='Get Total']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Get Total** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
  wd.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-first-form-demo.html");
  new WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.form-control#sum1"))).sendKeys("5");
  wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-control#sum2")).sendKeys("5");
  wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-default[onclick^='return total']")).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
  wd.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-first-form-demo.html");
  new WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and @id='sum1']"))).sendKeys("5");
  wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control' and @id='sum2']")).sendKeys("5");
  wd.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default' and text()='Get Total']")).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: seleniumeasy]